# AWS Amplify GraphQL API, how do I add onto the premade API calls?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

Is there a way to add on the premade GraphQL APIs that Amplify autogenerates? For example, I have a listTasks query call but I want to add more input fields. Does Amplify provide a way to do this easily? Right now I just copied the query and put it in my React component and modified the query.

Comment: You can write your own Input Type in your schema.graphql. You should read through https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli-toolchain/graphql

Comment: @KevinRegenrek Uhh I read it but still not sure. Are you talking about using '@connection' and '@key' to create a custom input?

Comment: I'm not sure on which fields you want to query but maybe you can add some keys to your model. https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/directives#key